# PGP Key in Funding Application

Tags: ether

I am looking to get funding from the [ECF Network](https://ecf.network/#about)  for an Ethereum project. They ask for a PGP key under the apply form ("Please make sure you paste your pgp public key here: ", but nowhere on their website or online can I find what they mean (I know it is an encryption key...but to what?). I don't want to ask before I ask for funding because I don't want to risk losing any chance of receiving funding due to perceived incompetence. Can anyone help explain what is required here?

Comment: PGP means [Pretty Good Privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) and it is a cryptographic software used for signing and encryption. There are open source implementations like [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/). Also it is optional to include a public PGP key: _Attaching your pgp public key would also be nice_.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Ismael. Okay, good to know. The question previously though asks "Please make sure you paste your pgp public key here: ". I suppose they said please, so it could be optional though...